# paypal ExpressCheckout force email address

Tags: email, paypal, controls, express-checkout

I have a constraint due to the french law which say that one customer must alway pay with the same PAYPAL account (the email is asked on my website).

My question is how can I force this mail address when the customer arrive on paypal page and disable the possibility to change it?

for informations I work with PHP.

Comment: Have you attempted anything?

Comment: Yes i can add the mail of the customer in parameter to fill the mail input but not force to use it.

Answer (score 0):

With ExpressCheckout you cannot force a person to log in with a specific email address. You can do it with [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/adaptive-payments/), however.

In your request for payment specify a `senderEmail` and they will only be able to use that to check out.

Comment: Thank you I'm going to look the Adaptive Payments API.